# Can I refer to components using variables in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, tlabel

I have many `TLabel`s, and instead of manually changing their `.Caption`s I'd like to do it in code. Something like

```
lbl[i]
```

instead of manually

```
lbl1 := x; 
lbl2 := y;
```

Comment: Yes, create a static or dynamic array of labels: `var Labels: array[1..10] of TLabel` or `var Labels: array of TLabel`. This has been asked many times before, and you will also learn to use arrays in any introductory Delphi or programming textbook.

Comment: Also please note that the question "Can I refer to components using variables in [D]elphi?" strictly speaking has nothing to do with your *actual* question. Indeed, even if you drop a single `TLabel` on your form, you do get a variable (`Label1`, say) that refers to it!

Comment: Take the [tour] to learn about formatting your post. Also a [**label** in programming terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Label_(computer_science)) is something different than the component `TLabel`, so take care of naming it unambiguously when posting again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the IDE to create the labels then you have two choices:

1. Use your own array:

   ```pascal
   // in public or private
   var Labels : array [1..2] of TLabel;

   // in OnFormCreate or similar event
   begin
     Labels[1] := Label1;
     Labels[2] := Label2;
   end;

   // somewhere else
   var
     lLabel : TLabel;
   begin
     for lLabel in Labels do lLabel.Caption := 'xyz';
   end;
   ```
2. Use the `TForm.Control` array of the Form you're currently in:

   ```pascal
   var
     I : integer;
     lControl : TControl;
   begin
     for I := 0 to ControlCount-1 do 
     begin
       lControl := Controls [I];
       if lControl is TLabel then (lControl as TLabel).Caption := 'xxx';
     end;
   end;
   ```

Comment: Here, to say thanks, you tick it as the answer.

Comment: @AmigoJack - Not complaining about the reformat of the code.  Everyone has their own style.  But when I am posting it for a beginner, I use more lines and white space for clarity :-)

Comment: Since 1995 it's the first time I've seen `do` on a new line (as opposed to be the end of a line) and it hardly makes sense to break/replace the pattern of `begin` being always the start of a line. What would be the advantage of that?